# Не получается сделать python manage.py makemigrations, в чем проблема и как ее решить?

Tags: django-model

[image: введите сюда описание изображения](env) PS D:\saycheeseandmusic> python manage.py makemigrations
C:\Python310\python.exe: can't open file 'D:\saycheeseandmusic\manage.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Выдает такую ошибку типа не видит файла manage.py, что делать???

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Очевидно, потому, что в каталоге D:\saycheeseandmusic\ не существует файла manage.py

Comment: А что делать - это вам лучше знать, куда вы дели свой файл manage.py

Comment: Он у меня в проекте есть, я не понимаю в чем проблема